# Sending a email from a hard coded email adress iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, email, smtp

I'm working on an app and I need it to send an automated email with variables Inputted from text boxes in the app. The email will be sent from a email address with a hardcoded in email adress and password and sent to another email, which is also hardcoded in. Is this possible and would apple allow this? I am currently doing this in android and I need the same thing in an IOS app. The email will be sent from googles gmail SMTP server, if this is useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Currently apple does not provide a way to send an email from an app without using the users email address that they have setup through the mail app.

You will have to hit a web service that would send an email, or implement your own smtp service in the app.

There is also a third party library option such as this [one](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-objc), however they say they are dropping support for it.

Not sure about Apple rejecting it if you try it, I would stick to calling a web service that sends the email for you.